# How to enable CORS on AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application hosted on AWS EB. The front end is made using Angular JS and backend is in PHP. I am now trying to make an ionic app for the same web application. I have my ionic setup on my local server and trying to access the remote APIs on the AWS server. When I try to do so I get 500 internal server error. I researched a lot on this topic and came to know that I need to enable CORS so that the local server is able to consume remote APIs.

I also checked the request header being set. I am sending 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' but still I get the same 500 error. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: you need to allow this CORS header in php code that you are deploying on aws elastic-beanstalk

Comment: Thanks. I enabled 'Allow all origin' header and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow all the CORS header in php code that you are deploying on aws elastic-beanstalk.